# FOSUserBundle: avoid logging in while confirming registration

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

when clickin on the link to confirm a registration, the new tab is open in the browser and a message about confirmation is shown. In the same time the user is also logged in. How to avoid this?

Comment: Which part do you want to not do?

Answer (score 2):

1. Override `\FOS\UserBundle\Security\LoginManager` class with your own. This login manager is used in the `AuthenticationListener` that's dispatched during the confirmation.

   fos_user.security.login_manager.class: namespace\YourUserBundle\Security\CustomLoginManager

Implementing the `loginUser()` method (e.g. return null) in your `CustomLoginManager` can disable auto login. However, do note that this **disables auto login for the following events** as well:

- FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED
- FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED
- FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_COMPLETED

(check - search - code when and where these are dispatched if this solution really suits your needs.)

---

2. Override  `\FOSUserBundle:RegistrationController::confirmAction` 
   and DO NOT dispatch the appropriate event. (see [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md) on how to override fosuser controllers)

Look for \FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED) in the base controller's confirm action for reference.

---

3. add a compiler pass to override/extend/implement your own `AuthenticationListener` that's being dispatched by the base fos user actions.

This is the most advanced, but leanest solution. See [CompilerPassDocs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html) on how to add one to your child bundle (the one extending fosuser). This is an example of the Compiler Pass file I propose:

```
class OverrideServiceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
     public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
     {
          $definition = $container->getDefinition('fos_user.listener.authentication');
          $definition->setClass('namespace\MyUserBundle\EventListener\CustomAuthenticationListener');
     }
}
```

Look at the original `\FOS\UserBundle\EventListener\AuthenticationListener` file for reference, add the proper events and implement the method(s) accordingly in your custom auth listener. (e.g. return null on `authenticate()` perhaps.)